# Passar string para uppercase - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Boa tarde. Tenho o seguinte codigo que salva perfeitamente.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'servidor' => 'required|unique:servidors|max:255',
       // 'dtprotocolo' => 'date|date_format:Y-m-d',
    ]);

    Servidor::create($request->all());

    Session::flash('create_servidor', 'Servidor cadastrado com sucesso!');

    return redirect(route('servidor.index'));
}
```

Porem eu gostaria de alterar o valor $request->servidor para uppercase.
Como proceder?

Comment: $comUpper = strtoupper($request->servidor); não da certo?

Comment: Da sim,  $request->servidor= strtoupper($request->servidor), porem quando vou salvar no banco,  Servidor::create($request->all()), ele volta para o original.

Comment: Juliano a resposta se foi a resposta da sua pergunta aceite como resposta

Comment: Tenta usando isso:
$data = $request->all();
$data['servidor'] = strtoupper($data['servidor']);
Servidor::create($data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua `model` `Servidor` faça um [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators) que o valor sempre será maiúsculo a partir dessa configuração, a partir desse código abaixo, como exemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Servidor extends Model
{
    // as outras configuração do seu model continuam

    // acrescente esse método
    public function setServidorAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['servidor'] = mb_strtoupper($value);
    }
}
```

Para maiores detalhes para configura um [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators) verifique na documentação [Defining A Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator).

<sub>Referencias:</sub>

- [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators)
- [Defining A Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)

Comment: oi amigo, estou iniciando em laravel, eu preciso chamar essa funcao em algum lugar no codigo ou basta declarar a mesma no model pra funcionar?

Comment: Na hora que você passar o valor para `$model->servidor = "novovalor"`será passado tudo para maiúsculo @ItaloRodrigo ou qualquer meio de passagem de valor para esse membro do objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver utilizando inputs, pode transforma o dados em maiúscula no momento da inserção do usuário. Utilize este javascript no final da page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// INICIO FUNÇÃO DE MASCARA MAIUSCULA
function maiuscula(z){
    v = z.value.toUpperCase();
    z.value = v;
}
//FIM DA FUNÇÃO MASCARA MAIUSCULA
```

no seu input, utilize chame a função:

```
<input name="cliente" class="form-control"  placeholder="nome cliente" onkeyup="maiuscula(this)">
```